# How to add a close button to Lightbox on Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

sorry for my English...

I to come this code from [here](https://gist.github.com/shrestharikesh/f4d094e0a64f10aa991733506fd9d791) but it to come without close Botton.

Top above on the Website I have,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

On my Html,

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <a href="photo/113.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-3" >
     <img src="photo/113.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded">
   </a>
   <a href="photo/2-2.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-3">
      <img src="photo/2-2.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded">
   </a>
   <a href="photo/3-2.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-3">
      <img src="photo/3-2.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded">
   </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

style.scss

```
.row {
    margin: 15px;
}

image { width: 70%; padding-left: 3rem;}
```

The Javacript Code,

```
$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

But how to show the image I did not come the close Button,

[image: show the image without close button]

Can Please someone with easy words to say how to add the close button?, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current design is to close it if you click somewhere else on the page.

```
[https://codepen.io/nsom/pen/VbqLew][1]
```

Here is how you can add the close button

```
$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  
  $(this).ekkoLightbox({alwaysShowClose: true});
});
```

Here is the link to the library that is used 
https://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Comment: Thanks!, but I'll the window with a close Button..it is that possible?

Comment: Very Thanks! my problem was that I knew that I should add `alwaysShowClos`  what I don' t knew where I don' t  know Javascript... I wish you a nice day!